# In Angular 2.4, failed to import a feature module from a different project to the main project

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-modules

I have two projects, one is the main project and the second project is a shared project.  Inside the shared project I have created a feature module called NavBar.

The reason why we separated into different projects is so that we can reuse the NavBar module in different projects.

I want to import the NavBar feature module to the main project by using

```
import { NavBarModule } from '../../SharedProject/app/shared/navbar/navbar.module'
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error which says it tries to import using a get method

> (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/ShareProject/app/shared/navbar/navbar.module

May I ask the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what could be wrong with your code, you haven't provide enough information/code.

Maybe this would be helpful:

[Angular 2 - moving modules to their own project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416445/angular-2-moving-modules-to-their-own-project/40417696#40417696)